# Delete a file when dialog box is closed?

Tags: mfc, cdialog

This is my code, and its working fine. 
However I would like to remove the file by variable `xmlfilepath` which I have mentioned in the `OnInitDialog()`

```
BOOL CTestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CString xmlfilepath = _T("C:\\Project\\Test\\test.xml");
    Navigate(xmlfilepath);
    return TRUE;
}

void CTestDlg::OnClose()
{
   CDHtmlDialog::OnClose();
   remove("C:\\Project\\Test\\test.xml");                   
}
```

Comment: Open the file using the delete-on-close creation disposition, and the system will clean up for you once the final handle to the file is closed. This ensures that the file will live as long as your dialog insurance does, and also clean up in case your application crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
class CTestDlg : public CDialog
{
  ...
  CString m_xmlfilepath;  // << put this somewhere in the definition
                        //    of CTestDlg
  ...
}


BOOL CTestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    m_xmlfilepath = _T("C:\\Project\\Test\\test.xml");
    Navigate(m_xmlfilepath);
    return TRUE;
}

void CTestDlg::OnClose()
{
   CDHtmlDialog::OnClose();
   remove(m_xmlfilepath);
}
```

This is really basic C++ knowledge. I suggest you learn the basics of C++ prior to experimenting with MFC.

Comment: If `OnClose` is not triggered in dialog then use `void CTestDlg::OnDestroy()` with `ON_WM_DESTROY()` in message map.

Comment: More likely than not, this will fail to account for object lifetimes. The question apparently uses [CDHtmlDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdhtmldialog-class), and it's not clear, how long that dialog holds a handle to the file in question. Calling `remove` in the `OnClose` (or even `OnDestroy`) handler is likely to fail.

Comment: @IInspectable the browser control doesn't lock the file, so the file can be deleted any time after its loaded (it won't refresh obviously). Also we are not passing a file handle, delete-on-close option is not clear. Not knowing exactly what's going on, maybe `OnNcDestroy` is better, or just put this in constructor/destructor.